# Use an isolated set of cookies in a page-worker

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am running code on a third-party website via a page-worker. This code touches cookies as a side-effect. I would like the side-effects to be contained within the invisible page-worker tab so as not to disturb the user's experience with the same site.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Cool question. I'm not sure how to do it on a tab. With XHR you might do this by using the `LOAD_ANONYMOUS` flag on the channel and the cookies returned by the headers, and keep track of yourself. And send it with future requests. On a tab maybe use `http-on-modify-request` to detect `loadContext` and if the `loadContext.associatedWindow` is your tabs window then strip the cookies on page requests, and on `http-on-modify-response` strip the `SetCookies` but stripping SetCookies on repsonse might be too late it might affect the cookies and then ALSO it might not affect in tab, confusing, nice q

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I had to look up some documentation so for everyone's reference, this is how to subscribe to http-on-modify-response and get the load context to match request and tab: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification_%28example_code_updated_for_loadContext%29

Comment: I got an idea on how to do it in a tab. Using that `http-on-modify-request` method to catch the `loadContext` and `associatedWindow` if it matches your tab, then on the channel set the `LOAD_ANONYMOUS` flag, its the same way on XHR. So now I know that `LOAD_ANONYMOUS` will for sure not use users cookies, so you can append to the headers cookies you want. But what I'm wondering and the thing that will make this method work is: IF the anonymous flag will PREVENT the `SetCookies` headers from setting cookies. If it does then this works, I want to write a test case for this soon, sounds real fun.

Comment: Couldn't I just read and process all incoming `Set-Cookie` and rewrite all outgoing `Cookie` headers (in channels related to my tab) regardless of the `LOAD_ANONYMOUS` flag?

Comment: Yeah thats what we should do but what Im worried about is `Set-Cookie` headers affecting the users actual cookies. I'm hoping that `LOAD_ANONYMOUS` flag will prevent this from happening but I'm not sure, we'll need to test it. Know what I mean?

Comment: How about erasing the `Set-Cookie` headers? At that time they would be stored in a sort of userland cookie jar, from which the request `Cookie` headers would be regenerated. (in my case that implies a separate authentication cookie, which might not be doable, so I'm just talking theory now)

Comment: Ah super idea, we gotta test this out! Awesome thinking togather session!